# Create launch configuration via AWS CLI with non-default VPC security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, aws-cli, autoscaling

I am creating autoscaling launch configuration via AWS CLI with this command

`aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name mylaunchconfig --key-name mykeypair --image-id ami-12345678589d597d1 --security-groups My-Private-SG --instance-type t3a.small`

While executing this command I'm getting this error

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateLaunchConfiguration operation: The security group 'My-Private-SG' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-abce07df'`

However, there is no option available to specify VPC ID in CLI

`aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration help`

```
  create-launch-configuration
      --launch-configuration-name <value>
      [--image-id <value>]
      [--key-name <value>]
      [--security-groups <value>]
      [--classic-link-vpc-id <value>]
      [--classic-link-vpc-security-groups <value>]
      [--user-data <value>]
      [--instance-id <value>]
      [--instance-type <value>]
      [--kernel-id <value>]
      [--ramdisk-id <value>]
      [--block-device-mappings <value>]
      [--instance-monitoring <value>]
      [--spot-price <value>]
      [--iam-instance-profile <value>]
      [--ebs-optimized | --no-ebs-optimized]
      [--associate-public-ip-address | --no-associate-public-ip-address]
      [--placement-tenancy <value>]
      [--cli-input-json <value>]
      [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

How can I create launch configuration along with specifying security group exists in non-default VPC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the **security-groupId** instead of **name**. The security-groupId is generated by aws.

your command should be something like below:

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name mylaunchconfig --key-name mykeypair --image-id ami-12345678589d597d1 --security-groups sg-xxxxxxxx --instance-type t3a.small
```

where `sg-xxxxxxxx` is your security-groupId.